# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext;

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xmpp

I'm trying to build a chat application with XMPP protocol using Smack library in android studio.
by using Smack version 3.1.0 I could easily connect to open fire server and even I sent a message to a user that were logged in by spark. but I could never receive a message from that user because the processMessage of MessageListener ran just once in compile. as I couldn't get the favorite result I searched over the internet and find out that smack from version 4.1 or upper just support in android.

so I tried to build my app with smack 4.1.4 and resolve many errors.
but one error didn't resolved and I couldn't find it on the internet.
that's it (of course there are too many more errors but I bring the top 4):

```
11-10 00:16:03.446 15512-15539/xmppconnectiontest2.ffisher.com.xmpp2  E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext;
11-10 00:41:36.169 19859-19886/xmppconnectiontest2.ffisher.com.xmpp2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.javax.JavaxResolver.<clinit>(JavaxResolver.java:50)
11-10 00:41:36.169 19859-19886/xmppconnectiontest2.ffisher.com.xmpp2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-10 00:41:36.169 19859-19886/xmppconnectiontest2.ffisher.com.xmpp2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
```

as the documents of igniterealtime said I add all of necessary libraries.
this is my dependencies in Gradle :

```
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-javax:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-bosh:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-legacy:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-jingle-old:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-debug:4.1.4'
```

the main activity onCreate :

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String [] param = {"mhs", "10.0.2.2"};
            Asynchron asynchron = (Asynchron) new Asynchron();
            asynchron.doInBackground(param);
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

the sub class of AsyncTask that I used :

```
public class Asynchron extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();

        builder.setServiceName(params[0]);

        builder.setHost(params[1]);

        builder.setPort(5222);

  builder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);

        builder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        builder.setCompressionEnabled(true);

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(builder.build());
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");

        try {
            connection.connect();
            connection.login("testUser1", "1234");

        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I really need your help.
how can I resolve the error I wrote in title of question?

Answer (score 3):

just use :

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.0"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"
```

and remove `builder.setCompressionEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 2):

Delete smack-resolver-javax in your dependencies. Probably that jar is overriding some legacy classes

Comment: yes it's worked! but unfortunately some another errors accrued :                    11-10 01:15:56.477 13926-13953/xmppconnectiontest2.ffisher.com.xmpp2 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'byte[] org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder.Base64$Encoder.encode(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Great! The new error, I Think is code related, the argument of encode appears to be null, check it

Comment: remove this code: builder.setCompressionEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

just use `smack-tcp`, `smack-experimental` and `smack-android-extensions`